# How to convert String to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an image that's path is stored in a variable of type string.
 How can I store that path in 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile', the file upload?

Please some one tell me how to convert a string to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.

Answer (score 1):

HttpPostedFile has a sealed constructor; you could use reflection to create the HttpPostedFile class.  The ctor takes: string fileName, string contentType, HttpInputStream stream

So you have to pass the path to the HttpPostedFile constructor via reflection if you like.  Not sure what by default gets passed to HttpInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public string SaveImageFile(FileUpload fu, string directoryPath, int MaxWidth, 
                            int MaxHeight, string prefixName)
{
    string serverPath = "", returnString = "";
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = fu.FileBytes;
        //Int64 len = 0;
        prefixName = "Testing" + prefixName;
        //directoryPath = "Testing/";
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        string dipath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + directoryPath;
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dipath);
        if (!(di.Exists))
        {
            di.Create();
        }
        HttpPostedFile file = fu.PostedFile;
        DateTime oldTime = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan structTimespan = currentTime - oldTime;
        prefixName += ((long)structTimespan.TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
        if (IsImage(file))
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file.InputStream, false))
            {
                serverPath = dipath + "//" + prefixName +     fu.FileName.Substring(fu.FileName.IndexOf("."));
                img.Save(serverPath);
                returnString = "~/" + directoryPath + "//" + prefixName + fu.FileName.Substring(fu.FileName.IndexOf("."));
            }
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}

private bool IsImage(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    if (file != null && Regex.IsMatch(file.ContentType, "image/\\S+") &&
      file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

SaveImageFile method returns a string which will be the path.